# Displaying a list that contains a list in .NET MAUI

Tags: maui

I have a list of items where each item contains a list of its own. Here's a simplified version of my classes:

```
public class Teacher
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public List<Student> Students { get; set; } = new();
}

public class Student
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public decimal GPA { get; set; }
}
```

So, I have a `var teachers = new List<Teacher>();` that I need to display. Here's the challenge: I need the final output to look like this in a `Grid` layout:

| Teacher / Student |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Teacher: John Smith |  |  |
| Brian Green (GPA: 3.7) | Joyce Smith (GPA: 3.2) | Robert Gonzalez (GPA: 3.62) |
| Teacher: Jane Doe |  |  |
| Liz Jones (GPA: 3.66) | James Pino (GPA: 3.17) |  |

I initially tried using `CollectionView` within a `CollectionView` which actually works fine with one pretty big problem. The first set of data displays nicely but the second and subsequent sets get pushed way down on the page and there's no way for the user to know that there's more data down below and they need to scroll down A LOT.

Setting the `HeightRequest` for `CollectionView`'s actually fixes the problem but because I can't predict the number of students each teacher will have, I can't set a `HeightRequest` for the `CollectionView`. Someone from the team told me that `CollectionView` tries to grab as much space as possible and that's what's causing this issue.

I could try to calculate and set the height of each `CollectionView` in runtime but I'm really not crazy about that idea.

What other options do I have to render a list within a list using a grid layout? I thought about using `BindableLayout` but I don't think I can render a grid layout with that.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

As @JessieZhang suggested, using groupings with `CollectionView` looks like the correct approach here but it requires some pre-processing. I'm still having trouble binding items to correct `DataType`.

Here's what I've done:

First, I created a new `StudentGroup` class that looks like this:

```
public class StudentGroup : List<Student>
{
   public string TeacherName { get; private set; }
   public StudentGroup(string teacherName, List<Student> students) : base(students)
   {
      TeacherName = teacherName;
   }
}
```

I, then, mapped my `List<Teachers>()` to `List<StudentGroup>()` with a `foreach`:

```
...
var studentGroups = new List<StudentGroup>();
foreach(var item in teachers)
{
   var studentGroup = new StudentGroup(item.Name, item.Students);
   studentGroups.Add(studentGroup);
}
```

Up to this point, everything seems to be working as intended. The problem is binding this to my `CollectionView`:

```
<CollectionView
   ItemsSource="{Binding StudentGroups}"
   IsGrouped="True">
   <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
      <DataTemplate>
   </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
   <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
      <HorizontalStackLayout>
         <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
         <Label Text="{Binding GPA}" />
      </HorizontalStackLayout>
   </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

This throws an error, stating `Name` and `GPA` are not found. If I add `DataType` to my `ItemTemplate`, I don't get a compile error but when I run it, the whole app crashes:

```
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Student">
     <HorizontalStackLayout>
        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
        <Label Text="{Binding GPA}" />
     </HorizontalStackLayout>
   </DataTemplate>
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: For your needs, it is recommended that you use [Display grouped data in a CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/grouping?view=net-maui-7.0) to achieve it.

Comment: This appears to be the right solution but I'm having trouble displaying students. In all examples, the Group object is not a completely separate object but one that inherits from its child i.e. `Teacher : List<Student>`. Does this mean I can't use a completely different object such as `Teacher` as parent/group object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your code, I created a demo and tried to achieve this function, and it works properly on my side.

You can refer to the following code:

**Student.cs**

```
public class Student 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal GPA { get; set; }
}
```

**Teacher.cs**

```
public class Teacher 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; } = new();
}
```

**StudentGroup.cs**

```
public class StudentGroup:List<Student> 
    {
        public string TeacherName { get; private set; }
        public StudentGroup(string teacherName, List<Student> students) : base(students)
        {
            TeacherName = teacherName;
        }
    }
```

**MyViewModel.cs**

```
public class MyViewModel 
{
    public List<StudentGroup> StudentGroups { get; private set; } = new List<StudentGroup>();

    public List<Teacher> Teachers { get; private set; } = new List<Teacher>();
    public List<Student> Students_A { get; private set; } = new List<Student>();
    public List<Student> Students_B { get; private set; } = new List<Student>();

    public MyViewModel() {

        Students_A.Add(new Student { Name = "Student1", GPA = 100 });
        Students_A.Add(new Student { Name = "Student2", GPA = 110 });
        Students_A.Add(new Student { Name = "Student3", GPA = 130 });

        Students_B.Add(new Student { Name = "Student4", GPA = 108 });
        Students_B.Add(new Student { Name = "Student5", GPA = 109 });

        Teachers.Add(new Teacher { Name = "teacher1", Students = Students_A });
        Teachers.Add(new Teacher { Name = "teacher2", Students = Students_B });

        // initlize StudentGroups
        //var studentGroups = new List<StudentGroup>();
        foreach (var item in Teachers)
        {
            var studentGroup = new StudentGroup(item.Name, item.Students);
            StudentGroups.Add(studentGroup);
        }
    }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiStuGroupApp"
             x:Class="MauiStuGroupApp.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:MyViewModel></local:MyViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" >

        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding StudentGroups}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  IsGrouped="true">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Student">
                    <HorizontalStackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding GPA}"  Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                    </HorizontalStackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

            <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Text="{Binding TeacherName}"
                           BackgroundColor="LightGray"
                           FontSize="20"
                           FontAttributes="Bold" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        </CollectionView>

    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: I have a strange crash problem but this definitely is the correct approach. Interestingly, if I remove the CollectionView and then add it back line by line while hot reload is running, everything works fine and I get the desired results. However if I stop debugging and start again, the app crashes. Not sure what about this code is causing the app to crash. It wasn’t crashing before this piece of code. Nevertheless, it’s the correct approach. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do its called "Nested CollectionView" or "Populate Nested data inside of a CollectionView"

you can use a `StackLayout` inside your CollectionView and set the property `BindableLayout.ItemsSource` with the nested object, in your case, you will use "Students" and that will allow you to populate a nested collection inside of a CollectionView, something like that

```
<StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    </StackLayout>
```

Using the CollectionView it will look like that (this is the final result), in this example you don't have to use a GroupHeader but any approach is good.
**MainPage.xaml**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="NestedLayout.MainPage">
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding StudentGroups}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="{Binding TeacherName}"
                       BackgroundColor="LightGray"
                       FontSize="20"
                       FontAttributes="Bold" />
                <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <HorizontalStackLayout>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding GPA}"  Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                            </HorizontalStackLayout>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

And my view model looks the same that the guy who show you the HeaderGroup Example

**MainPageViewModel.cs**

```
internal class MainPageViewModel
{
    public List<StudentGroup> StudentGroups { get; private set; } = new List<StudentGroup>();

    public List<Teacher> Teachers { get; private set; } = new List<Teacher>();
    public List<Student> Students_A { get; private set; } = new List<Student>();
    public List<Student> Students_B { get; private set; } = new List<Student>();
    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        Students_A.Add(new Student { Name = "Student1", GPA = 100 });
        Students_A.Add(new Student { Name = "Student2", GPA = 110 });
        Students_A.Add(new Student { Name = "Student3", GPA = 130 });

        Students_B.Add(new Student { Name = "Student4", GPA = 108 });
        Students_B.Add(new Student { Name = "Student5", GPA = 109 });

        Teachers.Add(new Teacher { Name = "teacher1", Students = Students_A });
        Teachers.Add(new Teacher { Name = "teacher2", Students = Students_B });

        // initlize StudentGroups
        //var studentGroups = new List<StudentGroup>();
        foreach (var item in Teachers)
        {
            var studentGroup = new StudentGroup(item.Name, item.Students);
            StudentGroups.Add(studentGroup);
        }

        
    }
}
```

advice: Never use a CollectionView inside of a CollectionView, this is a bad practice and OVERKILL even if it works, this is the way you can do it...

second advice: you don't need to initialize the Student list object in your Teacher object, you can remove that new from there

```
public class Teacher
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public List<Student> Students { get; set; } //<--- I mean this
}

public class Student
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public decimal GPA { get; set; }
}

public class StudentGroup: List<Student>
{
    public string TeacherName { get; private set; }
    public StudentGroup(string teacherName, List<Student> students) : base(students)
    {
        TeacherName = teacherName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response but this actually doesn't work for two reasons. First, the Grid is for students and not teachers which means `CollectionView` has to be the inner control which creates the second issue. Whenever multiple `CollectionView`'s are stacked one above the other, the original problem I mentioned happens. The subsequent `CollectionView`'s are rendrered but way down on the page and the user has to scroll quite a lot to get to them. I tried using a `VerticalStackLayout` as `BindableLayout` with `CollectionView` inside but I run into the original issue again.

Comment: I didn't see you have a main object called StudentGroup, but anyway, this approach would help you either, you only need to put your collection in this case StudentGroup as the main object of the CollectionView and inside your collectionview, I told you in my comment DON'T USE CollectionView inside BindableLayouts or Inside another CollectionView, an you say you try "I tried using a VerticalStackLayout as BindableLayout with CollectionView inside", see my example again... you need to use the collectionview FIRST,

Comment: Continue: in the item source you will past your StudentGroup object and inside the collectionview you will have two options, use a group header or use BindableLayouts inside, I will repeat search for nested collectionview

Comment: You can read my answer again, I adapted the code to your example, this code is fully tested and work perfectly...