# Handling long running computations in .NET MAUI

Tags: maui

In my .NET MAUI app, I have to make an API call, then do a bit of processing that takes a bit of time. If I do it as below, the app is crashing so I need to make sure the `MainThread` is not kept busy.

The following is the `Init()` method of my `ViewModel`.

```
public async void Init(Guid id)
{
   try
   {
       IsBusy = true;

       // Make API call to get data
       var data = await _myServices.Get(id);
       
       // Now process data that involves a foreach loop

       IsBusy = false;
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
       // Handle exception
   }
}
```

I've been doing some research on this but .NET MAUI being new, there's limited articles about this subject. Most of the information I've found pertain to Xamarin Forms.

Do I still use the `BackgroundWorker` to handle my data processing? If not, how do I handle a long running process and not tie up the `MainThread`? Also, should I handle the service/API call within that code block so that the API call is also handled by a thread other than the `MainThread`?

UPDATE:

The logs show a Watchdog Termination error with the following message:

> The OS watchdog terminated your app, possibly because it overused RAM

And it only happens on `iOS`. I have multiple `CollectionView`'s on the page that are bound to multiple `ObservableCollection`'s. One of the `CollectionView`'s displays grouped data so after my API call, I process the data and add it to one of the `ObservableCollection`'s so that I can use it as grouped data. This process, though doesn't process too much data, requires a `foreach` loop.

Initially, the app was crashing, not at startup, but as soon as I hit the page with `CollectionView`'s. I updated my code to the following:

```
public async void Init(Guid id)
{
   try
   {
       IsBusy = true;

       // Make API call to get data and process it for CollectionView with grouped data
       await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => {

       var data = await _myServices.Get(id);

       // Now process data to use in CollectionView
       var groupedData = new List<MyGroupedDataObject>();
       foreach(var item in data)
          // Do the conversion

       },TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

       IsBusy = false;
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
       // Handle exception
   }
}
```

This post shows how I go about processing the data for `CollectionView` with groups: [Displaying a list that contains a list in .NET MAUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75752414/displaying-a-list-that-contains-a-list-in-net-maui)

This initially appeared to have fixed the issue as hitting the page with multiple `CollectionView`'s no longer crashed the app. However, if I hit the page, then navigate to another page and come back, the app still crashes with the same Watchdog Termination error mentioned above.

I'm still looking into it but it certainly appears to be related to a memory management issue -- either I'm overusing the memory on the device and iOS is getting upset with that or as one GitHub post indicated, there maybe memory leak issues with `ObservableCollection`'s.

If anyone has any ideas/suggestions, I'd appreciate it if you let me know. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why the answer would be any different in MAUI than Xamarin Forms, or .NET in general

Comment: What exception is thrown here? You can use Tasks instead of BackgroundWorker. Task.Factory.StartNew(async ()=>{ [more async work here] }, , TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning) somewhere inside of your service's Get method.

Comment: Does using `Task` or `Task.Factory` guarantee that the `MainThread` won't be utilized for the operation? Someone mention, though not with 100% certainty, that using a `Task` does not necessarily guarantee that the `MainThread` won't be used for a `Task` operation. Do you know if this is the case or not?

Comment: `Task.Run` is the [modern replacement for `BackgroundWorker`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-intro.html). The code as posted doesn't look like it should throw any exceptions; please post more exception details.

Comment: @StephenCleary Logs show that it's a Watchdog Termination error and it only happens on iOS. As I look deeper, I think the issue is either some processing I do with the data I get from my API call which takes a bit of time, or it may be some type of memory issue -- either memory overuse or memory leak. The processing I do is to have a `CollectionView` with grouped data. I receive a `List<ParentObject>()` that contains a `List<ChildObject>()` and I convert this to `ParentObjectGroup` as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75752414/displaying-a-list-that-contains-a-list-in-net-maui

Comment: Wrapping your processing work in `await Task.Run(() => ...);` should do the trick, then.

Comment: @StephenCleary I added an update to original post -- see above. Still not sure what it is but the issue appears to be a memory management one.

Comment: @Sam: You shouldn't use `StartNew`. Use `Task.Run`, as I suggested.

Comment: I’ll give it a try now but I’m getting convinced that this is a memory issue. I’ll now try `Task.Run` and let you know if it helped. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: I figured out the problem. Originally, it was two issues. Doing the data processing in the `MainThread` was causing a delay and Watchdog termination was killing the app. As @StephenCleary suggested, using `Task.Run(() => ...);` helped with the `MainThread` issue but navigating away from the page and coming back still crashed the app which brings us to the second problem which is a bug in `CollectionView`'s with grouped data using `ObservableCollection`. Here's the GitHub issue: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10163

Comment: Glad you figured out the problem. Your comment is worth making an answer!